# Remove an email from outbox and re-edit

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code to delay sending messages by five minutes.

```vb
Dim obj As Object
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WkDay As Integer
Dim MinNow As Integer
Dim SendHour As Integer
Dim SendDate As Date
Dim SendNow As String
Dim UserDeferOption As Integer


Function getActiveMessage() As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set insp = Application.ActiveWindow
End If
If insp Is Nothing Then
    Dim inline As Object
    Set inline = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
    If inline Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set getActiveMessage = inline
Else
    Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set getActiveMessage = insp.CurrentItem
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
End Function


Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
SendDate = Now()
SendHour = Hour(Now)
MinNow = Minute(Now)
Set obj = getActiveMessage()
If obj Is Nothing Then
    'Do Nothing'
Else
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = obj
        SendMin = 5
        SendDate = DateAdd("n", SendMin, SendDate)
        Mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = SendDate
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I need a way to stop the item from sending. We can't delete it and start again as emails take a long time to compose and are highly detailed.

I'd like to add a button to the ribbon or context menu of Outlook 365, to re-open the email for editing and stop the deferred send.

I get

> an object can't be found

```vb
Sub MoveEmail()

Dim OutboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set OutboxFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
Set MoveFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Drafts")

Dim CurrentItem As Object
        
For Each CurrentItem In OutboxFolder.Items
    CurrentItem.Move MoveFolder
Next CurrentItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted, for anyone else...

```
 Sub MoveEmail()

      Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
      Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set OutboxFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
      Set MoveFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

      Dim CurrentItem As Object
            
      For Each CurrentItem In OutboxFolder.Items

            CurrentItem.Move MoveFolder

      Next CurrentItem

 End Sub
```

Comment: Do not use "for each" loop to iterate over a collection that you are modifying (by calling `Move`),. Use a down loop `from Count to 1 step -1`

Comment: @Dimitry I'd like to understand why I shouldn't be using the foreach loop if possible. How does the from Count work?

Comment: Because you are modifying modifying the collection you are iterating over causing your code to skip some entries.